# Change CSS on _Layout page depending on customer type and store DB values

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, background-color

I am trying to allow the site branding to be customisable per customer so that they can change certain colours to be applied to the website. I have these values stored in a database table and am able to retrieve them through the ViewModel. I was trying to use these to override the css but have been unable to do so. Here is what I am trying on the _Layout.cshtml page:

```
$('body').css('background', '#000000');
```

I put this to run on the load of the page so that the background would get changed to black but it does not seem to be working as the colour remains to that set in the default CSS file.

Comment: Your jQuery is fine, so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I have an alert before and after the statement which are both running, could this script be getting blocked in the head or are the default styles then overriding afterwards? If so any idea where I can override the CSS for the body tag?

Comment: It's difficult to say without actually seeing some code

Answer (score 0):

If possible it would be better to add a class to the body `<body class="@BodyClass">` which can be taken from the database. You could store `BodyClass` as the client name in lowercase e.g `river-island`.

Then you can control everything with a CSS file for that client:

```
body.river-island {
    /* styles */
}
```

It doesn't really make sense to store style values in a database and update the layout with JQuery on load. You will see performance issues when the site loads.

Comment: the problem is that when they change the body style its a base colour for buttons etc so I want to be able to override the selectors I already have in the stylesheet

Comment: The styles can be overridden `body.river-island .button` will override `body .button`

Comment: I am letting the user update the site styles using a color picker after saving the styles are automatically applied, I know I could do this inline on the page but this would prove very time consuming